# How to create different access permissions for GIT Remote Repository configured in local server

Tags: git

To Explain briefly, I have created a local GIT Repository.
I want to create branches on the repository i.e Dev, Test,Production. Different Branches should have different User access.

Dev-All users will have access.
Test-Limited access.
Production-Limited access.

I have seen the posts on Branch settings when repository hosted on GITHUB.
In my case, I have a remote repository on a local server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This not built in git alone, you will need a git server with these features, and access your shared repo through this server.

For web hosted options, I think you know the major names : github, gitlab.com or bitbucket

For self hosted options : have look at [gitlab (community edition)](https://about.gitlab.com/install/?version=ce) or [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Git itself does not define permissions. The security features you see on sites like GitHub are implemented on top of git.